# Swift - Firebase - Delete user account (Auth)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

I am trying to delete a user account already logged/auth with Twitter
->delete it from the Firebase Auth.

This code is executed when he press a button. I managed to log again and to catch the username/userID from Twitter but I still get this message :

> error: Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17014 "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request., error_name=ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN}
>   Optional("This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request.")

```
TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn(completion: { (session, error) in
    if (session != nil) {
        print("signed in as \(session?.userName)");
        print("signed in as \(session?.userID)");
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        user?.delete { error in
            if let error = error {
                // An error happened.
                print("error: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("deleted")
            }
        }
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete(completion: { (err) in                    
            print(err?.localizedDescription)                    
        })
    } else {
        print ("session is nil")
    }        
})
```

How can delete the Auth account from a user from the code ? (not with cloud functions)?

thanks,

Comment: Just to clarify, do you need to delete the auth reference in your application or to delete that account from twitter itself??

Comment: Hello @jms, I need to delete the Auth Reference in my app (not from twitter)

Comment: There should be a logout function to call. I am not familiar with the TWTRTwitter package. Can you look into this?

Comment: I read this : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#delete_a_user and it has to be taken from Firebase. Thus, I tried the re authentification like the doc said but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the reasons why the user is lost when consulting directly with Auth.auth (). CurrentUser? However, the correct thing to do is to use the session variable that comes as a result of the Completion. In this example I am authenticating with Phone Number but it corresponds to the same.

```
    let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
    withVerificationID: "some string",
        verificationCode: "some string")

Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in                        
    if error != nil {
        //do something
        }
        authResult?.user.delete(completion: { _ in
            //do something...
    })
}
```

In your code you must call the delete method from your session variable.